# Telerik Kendo StockChart column type doesn't display anything for 0 value

Tags: c#, charts, kendo-ui, telerik, markers

I have a chart, you can see it [on this link](https://jsbin.com/vijohaciko/edit?html,output) with markers

But when the series type is column and not line, like on my link, markers are not displayed. i.e.:

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
                dataSource: foreCast,
                seriesDefaults: {
                    type: "column",
                    style: "smooth"
                },
                series: [{
                    field: "temperature",
                    categoryField: "day",
                    markers: {
                        size: 12,
                        visible: true
                    }
                }],
                valueAxis: {
                    labels: {
                        template: "#:value#℃"
                    }
                },
            });
```

In telerik's doc, it seems ok :

> series.markers Object
>   Marker options.
>   ** Applicable for area and line series. **

But the issue is, when i have a value equals to zero, users can't tell if there is a value or not which is a problem for them.

Does a workaround exist to plot something (like a marker) when the value is 0 ?

Comment: I have found this [demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/oYAZO). Take a look on it if it helps you.

Comment: taking your demo and applying the same "demo" from @Ademar from: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/bar-charts/visuals, here is an updated version of your jsbin: https://jsbin.com/jehinakere/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on the answer/comment by @David Shorthouse

You can use the **[visual property](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-series.visual)** of the series as he suggests.  In that function you can test for a value of 0, and then draw a marker (small semi-circle in my example); and for non-zero values draw a regular bar according to the passed in color and dimensions.

Updated **[JSBIN](https://jsbin.com/gamaji/edit?html,output)**

```
visual: function (e) {   
    //get chart calculated coordinates of the bar and color                                         
    var xLeft = e.rect.topLeft().x;
    var xRight = e.rect.topRight().x
    var yTop = e.rect.origin.y;
    var yBottom = e.rect.bottomRight().y;
    var c = e.options.color;

    if (e.value == 0){
      //draw small (semi-)circle for zero values
      var center = e.rect.center();  
      var circleGeometry = new kendo.geometry.Circle([center.x, center.y], 5);
      var circle = new kendo.drawing.Circle(circleGeometry).stroke(c,2);
      return circle;
    } else {
      //Draw a regular bar
      var path = new kendo.drawing.Path({
          fill: {color:  c},
          stroke: {color: c,opacity: 0.7,width: 2,}
      })
      .moveTo(xLeft,  yBottom)
      .lineTo(xRight, yBottom)
      .lineTo(xRight, yTop)
      .lineTo(xLeft,  yTop)
      .close();

      return path; 
  }                          
}
```